# Is there a way to find a max value between a range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example,

```
l = [1, -9, 2, 5, 9, 16, 11, 0, 21]
```

and if the range is 10 (10 meaning any numbers higher than 10 wont be considered as the max), I want the code to return 9.

Comment: What should the answer be if _all_ the numbers in the list are > 10? BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, and it should return None in that cxase

Answer (score 5):

You can first delete all elements too large and then find the max:

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: x <= limit, list)
val = max(filtered, default = None) # the `default` part means that that's returned if there are no elements
```

`filtered` is a `filter` object which contains all elements less than or equal to the limit. `val` is the maximum value in that.

Alternatively,

```
filtered = [x for x in list if x <= limit]
val = max(filtered, default = None)
```

`filtered` contains all elements in the list if and only if they are less than the limit. `val` is the maximum of `filtered`.

Alternatively,

```
val = max((x for x in list if x <= limit), default = None)
```

This combines the two steps from the above method by using an argument comprehension.

Alternatively,

```
val = max(filter(limit.__ge__, list), default = None)
```

`limit.__ge__` is a function that means `x => limit >= x` (ge means Greater-Equal). This is the shortest and least readable way of writing it.

### Also please rename `list`

`list` is a global variable (the `list` type in Python). Please don't overwrite global variables ;_;

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh yeah, I was intending to complain about OP's choice of overwriting global variable names :P

Answer (score 0):

The following is not radically different, conceptually, than @HyperNeutrino's excellent answer, but I think it's somewhat clearer (per the [Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)):

```
from __future__ import print_function

l = [1, -9, 2, 5, 9, 16, 11, 0, 21]

def lim(x, n):
    if x <= n:
        return x

print(max(lim(a,10) for a in l))
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and most space efficient method is to utilize a conditioned generator expression:

```
maxl = max(num for num in l if num <= 10)
```

This loops over the list `l` once, ignoring any numbers not satisfying `num <= 10` and finds the maximum. No additional list is build.